# Loading Pytorch Bin Model Using Much More RAM Than Expected

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, large-language-model

I am trying to use the Mistral 7B parameter model from Hugging face, specifically trying to save it locally and then reload it. I have it under 4 bit quantization and the model size is only 3.5GB. However, upon reloading the model, my WSL RAM usage consumes all the 30GB+ of devoted RAM and crashes.

Code for downloading 4bit quantized model:

```
quantization_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.float16,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
)
model_id = "mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.1"

from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, pipeline
model_4bit = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id, device_map="auto", quantization_config=quantization_config, )
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
```

Code for saving model and model config:

```
accelerator = Accelerator()
new_weights_location = 'mistral_model_7B'
accelerator.save_model(model=model_4bit, save_directory=new_weights_location)
model_4bit.config.to_json_file('mistral_model_7B/config.json')
```

Code for reloading model from pytorch_model.bin file:

```
loaded_model = MistralForCausalLM.from_pretrained('mistral_model_7B')
```

The model downloads and runs fine, and the saved model file is only around 3.5GB. However, when I try to reload it for later usage, the memory consumption from the loading line in my WSL environment shoots up to consume all 15GB RAM and 15GB swap space, quickly crashing the kernel.

Also, if anyone knows a better way to save a 4bit quantized model that would be great. Currently `save_pretrained()` does not seem to work with 4bit quantized models.